# Is it valid to rank standardized beta coefficients from a zero-inflated model?

Tags: multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, zero-inflation

One way to get a rough idea of the relative importance of the covariates’ contribution to a linear model is to standardize them by their SE and then rank them by the magnitude of their absolute value. Greater magnitude means higher rank means more relative importance.

As I understand, zero-truncated and zero-adjusted models fit two regressions to the data, the first a logistic regression on the zeros and the second a regression on the count data. One must interpret the count model in context of the logistic model.

So question one is: Is it valid to rank the coefficients in this case? And if so, how?

Second question: If I have two models with different response variables, but the same covariates, can I compare ranks across the response variables?

For instance, imagine I have data modeling number of treats eaten by two different dog breeds with covariates like body size, saliva volume, hours since last treats, etc. If the data are zero-inflated and I use a two-part model, can I still compare the tops ranked covariate for breed A versus the top ranked covariate for breed B?